# Is there is relationship with browser cookies and C# cookies

Tags: c#, cookies

Can any body please explain answers to below questions to me. Beg your pardon if these are so silly.

1). If we set a cookie on a web page cookie will store as text file on our PC.
If we set a cookie from C# application (HttpWebRequest), is there any file going to be create like browser behavior?

2). Will say I have browse a some domain (eg: www.google.com) using my web browser and some cookies are set while I am browsing.
Then I started using my C# windows application and form that application it sends to requests to that domain(www.google.com) using HttpWebRequest.

My question is weather the cookies (which set while I am browsing) going to be send with that request.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# program does not create cookies. Only the client browser does. What your program does is sending an HTTP header to the browser, instructing it to create cookies in the computer it runs on.

When you use `HttpWebRequest`, it won't send cookies previously set by your program and submitted to the client machine, because your C# program is a sort of a distinct "browser". It will only send cookies you set to that object.

Comment: For the user who has downvoted: Would be polite and effective to comment why downvoted. Was my answer wrong or misleading etc.? Continuing that, you are more than welcome to write your own correct answer.

Comment: That means it is not possible to send previously stored cookies with the c# HttpWebRequest. So is there any suggestions to the my issue.

Comment: You didn't ask for suggestions neither you've said you have "an issue". You asked 2 specific questions, and I answered them. Another thing: I understand that you are new here; so you probably don't know - it's impolite to downvote the only person who tried to help you and answered your question.

Comment: I am not the person who down voted this. I think you misunderstood me. Any answer to my question will be really appreciated.The way you pointing out me is really bad. I just put the comment to get more help from you. Not as a reply to you comment. Really disappointed.           This is also impolite pointing out me for the down vote.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much for the answer which you gave me at very first.

Comment: From your phrasing I didn't understand that; I thought you are the one who downvoted because you asked "So is there any suggestions to the my issue." but you didn't detail any issue in your question, you just asked if cookies are going to be sent with the request. So I figured that since you felt that my answer doesn't address your issue (which wasn't detailed in your question, as I've explained) you have downvoted. Anyway, please update your question itself so it will be clear what you are trying or asking to do. Thanks

Comment: @NewDeveloper please consider marking the answer as accepted. It answers your question, and anyway there are no other answers.